# using tablesorter jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, hta

I'm having some problems using tablesorter to sort a table that is generated inside an hta. I don't know how to enable tablesorter on the new table.Bellow is a test html file. For testing purpose i recommend using IE  because contains VBS. Thx!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-us">
<head>
 <title>Test Tablesorter</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/chili-1.8b.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/docs.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
  $("table")
   .tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']})
   .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")});

 });
 </script>

</head>
<style>
table.tablesorter
{
 background-color: #CDCDCD;
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 8pt;
 margin: 10px 0pt 15px;
 text-align: left;
 width: 100%;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr th, table.tablesorter tfoot tr th
{
 background-color: #e6EEEE;
 border: 1px solid #FFF;
 font-size: 8pt;
 padding: 4px;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .header
{
 background-image: url(img/bg.gif);
 background-position: center right;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 cursor: pointer;
}
table.tablesorter tbody td
{
 background-color: #FFF;
 color: #3D3D3D;
 padding: 4px;
 vertical-align: top;
}
table.tablesorter tbody tr.odd td
{
 background-color: #F0F0F6;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp
{
 background-image: url(img/asc.gif);
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown
{
 background-image: url(img/desc.gif);
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown, table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp
{
 background-color: #8dbdd8;
}
</style>

<body>

<script language="VBscript">

Sub CheckSystem
strHTML = strHTML & "<table cellspacing='1' class='tablesorter' id='table'>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<thead> "
strHTML = strHTML & "<tr>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<th>Name</th>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<th>Major</th>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<th>Sex</th>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<th>English</th>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<th>Japanese</th>"
strHTML = strHTML & "</tr>"
strHTML = strHTML & "</thead> "
strHTML = strHTML & "<tfoot> "
strHTML = strHTML & "<tr>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<th>Name</th>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<th>Major</th>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<th>Sex</th>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<th>English</th>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<th>Japanese</th>"
strHTML = strHTML & "</tr>"
strHTML = strHTML & "</tfoot> "
strHTML = strHTML & "<tbody>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<tr>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<td>Student01</td>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<td>Languages</td>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<td>male</td>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<td>80</td>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<td>75</td>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<tr>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<tr>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<td>Student02</td>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<td>Languages</td>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<td>male</td>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<td>80</td>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<td>60</td>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<tr>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<tr>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<td>Student03</td>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<td>Languages</td>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<td>male</td>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<td>60</td>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<td>40</td>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<tr>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<tr>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<td>Student04</td>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<td>Languages</td>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<td>male</td>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<td>30</td>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<td>20</td>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<tr>"
strHTML = strHTML & "</tbody>"
strHTML = strHTML & "</table>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<span id='pager' class='pager'>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<form>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<img src='img/first.png' class='first'/>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<img src='img/prev.png' class='prev'/>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<input type='text' class='pagedisplay'/>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<img src='img/next.png' class='next'/>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<img src='img/last.png' class='last'/>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<select class='pagesize'>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<option selected='selected' value='5'>5</option>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<option value='10'>10</option>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<option value='30'>30</option>"
strHTML = strHTML & "<option  value='40'>40</option>"
strHTML = strHTML & "</select>"
strHTML = strHTML & "</form>"
strHTML = strHTML & "</span>"

DataArea.InnerHTML = strHTML
End Sub
</script>

<body>
<p><span id="DataArea"></span></p>
<input type="button"  class="button" value="CheckSystem" style="width:70" onClick="VBScript:CheckSystem">



</body>

</html>
```

With the help received from dartacus who pointed me to the right direction i managed to find a temporary sollution wich doesn't involves timeout (pagination still not working right)

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 


 $(document).ready(function(){

  $('#test-tablesorter').click(function(){
   $('table').addClass('tablesorter').tablesorter();
   $('table')
   .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")});
  }); 


});

</script>
```

I added id="table-sorter" to the button. There are some issues about pagination plugin of this script over the internet. I need to investigate further.

I have found the problem with pagination. It was caused by the the missing "/" at the end of each raw. My original post doesn't close properly the raw(might happened when i copy/pasted the code to create more data). The table syntax was the issue: "<"/tr">"

Answer (score 0):

Two things occur:

1) Are you calling tablesorter on table#table before it has been rendered in the browser by the vbscript further down the page? The table may not exist yet to be sorted.

2) I've never actually used a tfoot element, but does it not have to come after the tbody?

HTH,

G

---

Okay, you could try this instead. I haven't completely tested it, but it might help.

The jquery stuff has been put into a document.ready handler, and the function that makes the table sortable has a timeout set so that there is a delay of a second to allow the table to be rendered before making it sortable.

G

```
    function initTableSort(){

    $("table").tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']});
    $("table").tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")});

}

//execute when doc loaded
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('input#tableCreateBtn').click(function(){

    //give the table 1000 milliseconds to load before calling the fn which
    //makes it sortable

        setTimeout("initTableSort()", 1000);

    });

});
```

Comment: 1. i don't know how to call tablesorter after the table gets render.Any help is appreciated.2.It doesn't mater where the tfoot is specified(as far as i know).

Comment: i had time to test it and it's working, BUT...click once the table is getting sorted, click twice the table disappear, click once again the table is visible....Any suggestion?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, no - I was not able to duplicate the behaviour you describe with the tablesorter line commented out (I do not have this plugin available).

Comment: This is the link from original website http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Download. Download lastest jquery, tablesorter and tablesorter pagination plugin if you have time to experiment

Comment: i think the problem is the pagination plugin, if i don't render the pagination the table sort fine. i'll see what i can do from now on. Thanks  for your time

Comment: No worries, glad that you're on the path to a fix. G